# How to fix open file descriptors of a running process after device unplug?

Tags: linux, mount, nvme, file-descriptors

I have a process running that reads/writes to a file on my nvme `/nvmedisk/file`.

My nvme disk failed for some reason and it disappeared from `lsblk` but was listed with `lspci`.

I manually rebound it `echo 0000:0b:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/bind`.

I couldn't umount `/nvmedisk` because it was busy, `lsof`:

```
process    80452 gospo  234u   REG              259,1   411951104   84928 /nvmedisk/file
```

I umounted with `umount -l /nvmedisk` and mounted the nvme disk again `mount /dev/nvme1n2p1 /nvmedisk`

The disk is working fine but the process running is still hanging. If I open a file in `/nvmedisk` `lsof` yields disk identifier `259,9` instead of `259,1`. How can I fix the already open file descriptors so that the running process can resume.

The assumption is that the process repeatedly retries writing/reading using the file descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is using gdb to create a new file descriptor and replace the old one with the new one.

```
(gdb) p (int)dup2(open("/nvmedisk/file", 1090), 234) // 1090 for O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND
```